# Length of a disjunction

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

Simple question: I'm trying to count the number of `Roots` to an equation. But both `Length[x==1]` and `Length[x==1||x==2]` return a value of `2`. `Length` on longer expressions work fine. For example `Length[x==1||x==2||x==5||x==5]` returns `4` (which is what I want). It's just the case where I want the output of `1` that seems to be letting me down. What's the trick here to getting the right answer for `x==1`?

Comment: What is `x` in your examples above?

Comment: If x has not been assigned any numeric value then f[x_ == n_] := 1; f[Or[x__]] := Length[x]; followed by f[x == 1] or by f[x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 5 || x == 5] seems to give you what you want. Check that carefully for all the possible inputs you can give that.

Answer (score 4):

The simple function, `Count[#, _Equal, {0, -1}] &` works well.

```
roots = x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 5 || x == 5; roots2 = x == 1 || x == 2; roots1 = x == 1;
Count[#, _Equal, {0, -1}] & /@ {roots, roots2, roots1}
(* {4, 2, 1} *)
```

Note that the third argument, `{0, -1}`, is necessary in order to obtain the correct answer for `roots1`.

Answer (score 3):

A small function can do it.

```
roots = x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 5 || x == 5;
roots2 = x == 1 || x == 2;
roots1 = x == 1;

numRoots[expr_] :=
 Module[{rootList = Apply[List, expr, {0, 1}], listDimensions},
  listDimensions = Dimensions@rootList;
  If[Dimensions@listDimensions == {1}, 1, First@listDimensions]
  ]

numRoots[#] & /@ {roots, roots2, roots1}
(* {4, 2, 1} *)
```

The function converts the head of `expr` (`Or` in this case) and the heads at level 1 (`Equal` in this case) to `List` [evaluate `roots//FullForm`]. This gives a nested list of the components of the disjunction. `Dimension` will now `{2}` from `roots`, `{2, 2}` for `roots2`, and `{4, 2}` for `roots4`. We just have to check how many entries are in the dimension list to return the number of roots.